# audio element not playing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have an assignment to create an audio visualizer, but for whatever reason I cannot figure out how to play the audio in my code. I replicated the code from the previous assignment, which has a working audio element, but it is not playing for some reason.

Here is the relevant javascript in my version

```
let canvasElement, drawCtx;
    canvasElement = document.querySelector('canvas');
    drawCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

    let playButton, audioCtx, audioElement, sourceNode, analyserNode, gainNode;
    const NUM_SAMPLES = 256;
    let audioData = new Uint8Array(NUM_SAMPLES/2);
    const SOUND_PATH = Object.freeze({
        sound1: "media/New Adventure Theme.mp3",
        sound2: "media/Peanuts Theme.mp3",
        sound3:  "media/The Picard Song.mp3"
    });

    // main functions

    function setup()
    {
        setupWebAudio();
        setupUI();
        loop();
    }

    function setupUI()
    {
        addShapeButton.onclick = addShape;
        document.querySelector(".fa-plus").onclick = showHide;

        playButton = document.querySelector("#playButton");
        playButton.onclick = e =>
        {
            console.log(`audioCtx.state = ${audioCtx.state}`);

            // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
            if (audioCtx.state == "suspended")
            {
                audioCtx.resume();
            }

            if (e.target.dataset.playing == "no")
            {
                audioElement.play();
                e.target.dataset.playing = "yes";
            }
            else if (e.target.dataset.playing == "yes")
            {
                audioElement.pause();
                e.target.dataset.playing = "no";
            }
        }
    }

    function setupWebAudio()
    {
        const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        audioCtx = new AudioContext();

        audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
        audioElement.src = SOUND_PATH.sound1;

        sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

        analyserNode = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

        analyserNode.fftSize = NUM_SAMPLES;

        gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
        gainNode.gain.value = 1;

        sourceNode.connect(analyserNode);
        analyserNode.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

        audioElement.src = "media/New Adventure Theme.mp3";

        audioElement.onended =  _ => {
            playButton.dataset.playing = "no";
        };

        gainNode.gain.value = 50;
        //audioCtx.resume();
        audioElement.play();
    }
```

And here is the code in the previous, working version.

```
window.onload = init;

    // SCRIPT SCOPED VARIABLES

    // 1- here we are faking an enumeration - we'll look at another way to do this soon 
    const SOUND_PATH = Object.freeze({
        sound1: "media/New Adventure Theme.mp3",
        sound2: "media/Peanuts Theme.mp3",
        sound3: "media/The Picard Song.mp3"
    });

    // 2 - elements on the page
    let audioElement,canvasElement;

    // UI
    let playButton;

    // 3 - our canvas drawing context
    let drawCtx

    // 4 - our WebAudio context
    let audioCtx;

    // 5 - nodes that are part of our WebAudio audio routing graph
    let sourceNode, analyserNode, gainNode;

    // 6 - a typed array to hold the audio frequency data
    const NUM_SAMPLES = 256;
    // create a new array of 8-bit integers (0-255)
    let audioData = new Uint8Array(NUM_SAMPLES/2);

    let maxRadius = 200;

    let invert = false, tintRed = false, noise = false, sepia = false;

    // FUNCTIONS
    function init(){
        setupWebaudio();
        setupCanvas();
        setupUI();
        update();
    }

    function setupWebaudio(){
        // 1 - The || is because WebAudio has not been standardized across browsers yet
        const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        audioCtx = new AudioContext();

        // 2 - get a reference to the <audio> element on the page
        audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
        audioElement.src = SOUND_PATH.sound3;

        // 3 - create an a source node that points at the <audio> element
        sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

        // 4 - create an analyser node
        analyserNode = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

        /*
        We will request NUM_SAMPLES number of samples or "bins" spaced equally 
        across the sound spectrum.

        If NUM_SAMPLES (fftSize) is 256, then the first bin is 0 Hz, the second is 172 Hz, 
        the third is 344Hz. Each bin contains a number between 0-255 representing 
        the amplitude of that frequency.
        */ 

        // fft stands for Fast Fourier Transform
        analyserNode.fftSize = NUM_SAMPLES;

        // 5 - create a gain (volume) node
        gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
        gainNode.gain.value = 1;

        // 6 - connect the nodes - we now have an audio graph
        sourceNode.connect(analyserNode);
        analyserNode.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    }

    function setupCanvas(){
        canvasElement = document.querySelector('canvas');
        drawCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    }

    function setupUI(){
        playButton = document.querySelector("#playButton");
        playButton.onclick = e => {
            console.log(`audioCtx.state = ${audioCtx.state}`);

            // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
            if (audioCtx.state == "suspended") {
                audioCtx.resume();
            }

            if (e.target.dataset.playing == "no") {
                audioElement.play();
                e.target.dataset.playing = "yes";
            // if track is playing pause it
            }
            else if (e.target.dataset.playing == "yes") {
                audioElement.pause();
                e.target.dataset.playing = "no";
            }

        };

        let volumeSlider = document.querySelector("#volumeSlider");
        volumeSlider.oninput = e => {
            gainNode.gain.value = e.target.value;
            volumeLabel.innerHTML = Math.round((e.target.value/2 * 100));
        };
        volumeSlider.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("input"));

        let radiusSlider = document.querySelector("#circleRadiusSlider");
        radiusSlider.oninput = e => {
            maxRadius = e.target.value;
            circleRadiusLabel.innerHTML = Math.round((e.target.value));
        };
        radiusSlider.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("input"));

        document.querySelector("#trackSelect").onchange = e =>{
            audioElement.src = e.target.value;
            // pause the current track if it is playing
            playButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
        };


        // if track ends
        audioElement.onended =  _ => {
            playButton.dataset.playing = "no";
        };

        document.querySelector("#fsButton").onclick = _ =>{
            requestFullscreen(canvasElement);
        };

        document.querySelector("#tintRedCheck").checked = tintRed;
        document.querySelector("#tintRedCheck").onchange = e =>{
            tintRed = e.target.checked;
        }

        document.querySelector("#invertCheck").checked = invert;
        document.querySelector("#invertCheck").onchange = e =>{
            invert = e.target.checked;
        }

        document.querySelector("#noiseCheck").checked = noise;
        document.querySelector("#noiseCheck").onchange = e =>{
            noise = e.target.checked;
        }

        document.querySelector("#sepiaCheck").checked = sepia;
        document.querySelector("#sepiaCheck").onchange = e =>{
            sepia = e.target.checked;
        }
    }
```

I cannot seem to find a difference between the two, and I am out of ideas for debugging methods. My apologies that this is not a terribly relevant question for people to learn from in the future, but any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `AudioContext` playback expected to begin following user action or programmatically by code alone? See [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: It is supposed to begin on pressing the play button, but currently this does not happen, on my version, I mean. However, the method is properly being called because the console.log() lines are writing properly.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: Here's my attempt at using plnkr.co: https://plnkr.co/edit/ajDctKSKDqL2FJ21kl38 I could not figure out how to upload the mp3, but the url isn't the issue, so that isn't too important, I don't think.

Comment: Why are both `<audio>` and `AudioContext` used?

Comment: `MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play the media when a media element is passed to `.createMediaElementSource()` within `setupUI` `fetch()` to resource use `Body.blob()` to get the resource as a `Blob`, within chained `.then()` use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a `Blob URL` to avoid

```
MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for https://path/to/resource
```

error.

Move `.play()` outside of the following `if` statement or set `e.dataset.playing` to `"no"` before the user clicks `"Play"`

```
if (e.target.dataset.playing == "no") {}
```

The following code

```
shapes[myShapeIndex].rot = myRotationList.childNodes.item(1).childNodes.item(0).value;
```

logs the error

```
(index):381 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null
at valueLink ((index):381)
at loop ((index):249)
```

though the media does play.

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/ktPHaFA2SPOzQTBQHGNN?p=info